# Ubuntu: irqbalance - new install - does it need a reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, central-processing-unit

Ubuntu 10.04 kernel  2.6.36

some of our VPS's were crashing the last few days due to cpu load with Java (cpu_hung for 120 seconds errors on console)
installing irqbalance seems to have resolved the issue.

But, it did not require a reboot after installing.
Is this normal?
I am asking because this is something I need to install on all my servers and I need to be 100% sure irqbalance does not require a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Ubuntu and other Debian-based distros will start a service as soon as it's installed; Red Hat based distros do not.

In either case it's not necessary to reboot; if the service hadn't been started automatically as part of the installation, you could have started it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.I was wondering how the process/service (irqbalance) could actually take control of CPU requests and "balance" them accordingly without a reboot after the service is installed.

Comment: irqbalance (and any other service) starts working as soon as the service is started. Since Ubuntu starts services automatically when you install them, you should be set.

Comment: @TomG: It begins monitoring IRQs being received and updating the CPU IRQ masks. Any process (with suitable permissions) can do either thing at any time. For example, `cat /proc/interrupts` (show interrupts by CPU) or `echo 1 | /proc/irq/9/smp_affinity` (set IRQ 9 to be handled only by CPU 0). You can even run irqbalance in one shot mode to just set the IRQ-to-CPU mapping once and then terminate.